# Video Streaming via RTMP on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, streaming

Is there a tool available for Ubuntu that can stream shuffled playlists or folders of videos to my Wowza Server (hosted elsewhere) via RTMP?

I currently have an old iMac streaming videos via screen capture to the Wowza server, but I hope to find something that would allow to me to stream videos using Linux instead.

Liquidsoap has the ability to handle video, but doesn't support RTMP, nor Wowza. 
As far as I'm aware, VLC doesn't have the ability to stream playlists of videos on shuffle.

Any leads would be wonderful.

Comment: Look at this: http://erlyvideo.org/

Comment: ffmpeg supports rtmp as an output protocol.

Comment: @ymn - have you had experience using ERLYVIDEO before? Looks very interesting but can't my head around the weak documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) that is able to [concatenate inputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) (in your case shuffled), transcode stream into common format (e.g. H.264 + AAC) and [output to RTMP server](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) (e.g. Wowza)